# Apache with JKMount and Alias

Tags: apache

I am currently having issue with apache config with JKMount and Alias.

I mounted my application with JKMount

```
    JkMount /app1/*.jsp app1
    JkMount /app1/* app1
```

I have some static images on my local file system.

if the url is like http://testapp.com/app1/capture/testImg.jpg then I have to serve the image from my C:/capture/testImg.jpg.

For this I used AliasMatch

```
AliasMatch /app1/capture/(.*)$ C:/capture/img/$1
```

The problem here I can't use AliasMatch in conjection with JKMount.

If I comment JKMount part then I can access image. But my application is not working.

If I uncomment JKMount part my application is working but I can't access images.

This is my configuration in httpd.conf

```
   NameVirtualHost testapp.com
   <VirtualHost testapp.com:80> 
        ServerName testapp.com
    DocumentRoot "Z:\TestApp\app1\src\main\webapp\public"
    AliasMatch /app1/capture/(.*)$ C:/capture/img/$1 
    #<Directory C:/capture/img/>
    #   Order Deny,Allow
    #   Allow from all
    #</Directory>
    RewriteEngine on   
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://testapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    JkMount /app1/*.jsp app1
        JkMount /app1/* app1


    <Directory  C:/capture/img/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

       ErrorLog "z:\logs\apache_error_log"
       CustomLog "z:\logs\log_custom" combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Can any one help me with above issue

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have gone through Apache Tomcat Documentation.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/printer/apache.html

You could use no-jk env var to fix problem with mod_alias or mod_userdir directive when jk and alias/userdir URLs matches.

So My new httpd.config is looking like this

```
NameVirtualHost testapp.com
<VirtualHost testapp.com:80> 
    ServerName testapp.com
    DocumentRoot "Z:\TestApp\app1\src\main\webapp\public"
    #AliasMatch /app1/capture/(.*)$ C:/capture/img/$1 

    RewriteEngine on   
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://testapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/app1/capture/*" no-jk
    Alias /app1/capture/ C:/capture/img/

    <Directory  C:/capture/img/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


     JkMount /app1/*.jsp app1
     JkMount /app1/* app1

   ErrorLog "z:\logs\apache_error_log"
   CustomLog "z:\logs\log_custom" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything working fine for me.